# Using Jinja Template control flow with Argo Workflow

Tags: jinja2, argo-workflows

I have a query related with Argo Workflow & JINJA template:

I know Argo workflow support JINJA template for expressions like: {{ ... }},
But does Argo workflow also supports JINJA template control structures like: {% ... %} ........ or not?

I am struggling with one use case, where I need to add below statement in “Single” WorkflowTemplate

```
{% if inputs.parameters.resources.gpu == 1 %}
    nvidia.com/gpu: {{ inputs.parameters.resources.gpu }}
{% end %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argo Workflows [does not currently support Jinja control structures](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues/1293).

If you're okay with a little code duplication, one workaround would be to use [conditionals](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/tree/master/examples#conditionals) to implement a `gpu == 1` and a `gpu != 1` branch (as different steps).

You could also use [`podSpecPatch`](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/examples/pod-spec-patch.yaml). It's a JSON string representation of a patch to be applied to a pod spec. For simple variations within that JSON, you could probably use Jinja string templating. For more complex mutations, you could generate the JSON in a step and then use it as an output parameter.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal you bet! I just remembered a second possible workaround, so be sure to check the update.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will try jinja control structures inside podSpecPatch. But my requirements is little complex (i just mentioned one scenario in this question). 

I was trying to find some clean way to reduce multi-step tasks into single task (inside WorkflowTemplate), but looks like multi-step tasks (with conditionals) are better fit for my requirement.